# how to disable automatic ellipsis in IOS

Tags: html, css, ios, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on a web app that part of which is to display a description per location taken from an API. I have it so it displays the whole description no matter how long it is. when I run the app in developer mode and even when I deploy it to firebase it works just fine, it shows me the description no matter how long it is. tested it on my phone (android) and works just as well, but a co-worker tried it out on his iPhone and after a few lines it shows applies `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, thus not showing me the rest of the string and in turn replacing it with an ellipsis. I wasn't able to find much info on this problem so I wanted to ask if there are any relevant info sites out there for this sort of issue, and if anyone knows how do I disable this CSS property on IOS devices.

for additional context, the app is developed on Ionic-Angular

Comment: Please post the HTML and any relevant CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is a few months late but the only solution I found was going into settings>general>keyboard>text replacement and then doing the following:

In a text, or notes, or anywhere you can type (even copy these if you want: ... ) type two periods, put a space, then type another.
Now go back and delete that space between the two and all 3 will still be periods, not merged into an ellipsis. Select and copy those 3 (or the 3 I gave above) and now create new text shortcuts. I made 4 just to be safe and here they are:

1] the phrase is the pasted 3 periods, and the shortcut is an actual ellipsis (you can also type it by long pressing on the period on your iPhone)

2] the phrase is the pasted 3 periods and then the shortcut is the same pasted 3 periods (sometimes this makes the phone recognize something differently)

3] the phrase is the pasted 3 periods and the shortcut is two periods (so: .. ) and this way if I type 2 periods and hit space, it’ll turn it into 3 periods, not an ellipsis

4] the phrase is the pasted 3 periods and the shortcut is four periods (so: .... ) and this way if I type 4 periods and hit space it’ll turn it into 3 periods, not an ellipsis with a dot after it.

It’s not a perfect work around but if you almost always use 3 dots and don’t need 2 or 4 that often then this stopped the ellipsis from showing up for me (luckily!)

Edit: after playing around with it I found that the iPhone’s input of an ellipsis depends on where you are typing. For instance if I’m in a green text message chat (someone on android) it does not input it... so then when I type 3 periods, it replaces it to 4 since it sees the first by itself and the next 2 as being a shortcut to 3... grrrr...

So with that said, my solution above works for iMessages when texting people who have iPhones. This is primarily where I use 3 periods so I’ll probably keep mine this way. However, you can delete 3 of the 4 shortcuts I recommended and simply keep the 4 period shortcut one. Then every time you need 3 periods instead of an ellipsis, simply type 4 periods and move on..